# Typechecking state in mapStateToProps with typescript and redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Is there a way to typecheck only the substate for the container?

This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: rootStateType) => (state.subState);
```

I'd like to avoid creating a dependency between my rootReducer and all containers just for typechecking purposes. I think it makes sense that each container is only concerned with its own subState and typechecks that.

I had an idea of doing the following instead, but to my understanding it will not typecheck the destructured object, but typecheck before destructuring happens.

```
const mapStateToProps = ({subState}: subStateType) => (subState);
```

Any ideas? Not really sure what the convention is, maybe it's just simply better to typecheck the whole state in each container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's common in redux applications to decouple components from state by using selectors, functions that return a slice of state or computed value from state.

In your case, if you had a selector like

```
const getSubState = (state): subStateType => state.subState;
```

Then you could use it with mapStateToProps, and the slice of state would be typed accordingly. You can keep these selectors in the same module as your reducers and import them into your components.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => getSubState(state);
```